# Google maps api v3 affecting fixed elements in very strange ways

Tags: google-maps-api-3, css-position

URL of issue: [REMOVED]

I'm having issues where my fixed header is distorting itself whenever I resize the window, scroll the page, or mouse over elements. It's even affected by how *fast* I scroll. I have found others with similar issues, but trying the solutions have not resolved it.

CSS of fixed element:

```
#header-wrap {
    background: url(/_images/template/wood-background.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 56;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

One of the solutions called for adding the transform property, which did fix the issue some of the time.

Comment: the google map is not loaded, `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://mpfoods.dwgreen.com/locations/_scripts/respond.min.js`

Comment: That is not my google maps script, but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: OK, thought it broke some JS, here - ubuntu/chrome, the google map is completely empty

Comment: You're right. I haven't set the actual coordinates yet. But I don't see how that could affect what I'm talking about. I'll set a dummy coordinate for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remove :

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

everything seems to be allright.

Comment: This seems to be working for me, too. Although leaving it on fixed seems to be working, as well, now. So finnicky! Thanks for the help